# MVC dropdownfor deosnt show selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the CSHTML page below so that I am able to edit a list of sugestions models, I have idenified the information is being added to each of the rows, but when i change it to the dropdownfor it doesnt seem to select the value that is from sugested bubject Id's any ideas, the list is displayed fine but no information is selected when it is loaded.
Any ideas why this is happening.

```
        @model List<CISI.Mvc.Models.SuggestionModel> 
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC
        @using Telerik.Sitefinity.UI.MVC.Helpers
        <div class="container">
            @using (Html.BeginFormSitefinity("edit", "edit"))
            {

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                <fieldset>
                    <table style="border:4px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Subject ID
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Suggestion order
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Suggested subject
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].subject_id, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].suggestion_order)
                                </td>
                                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m[i].suggested_subject_id, Model[i].sugestedSubject)
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
                    <input type="submit" value="confirm" runat="server" />
                </fieldset>
            }
        </div>

      public List<eLearningSubjectSuggestionModel> getSubjectSuggestionsEdit(int subjectID)
            {
               // moduleSuggsetionList list = new moduleSuggsetionList();
                List<SubjectSuggestionModel> list2 = (from c in db.subject_suggestion_tbl
                                                              where c.subject_id == subjectID && c.deleted == false
                                                              orderby c.suggestion_order
                                                              select new SubjectSuggestionModel
                                                              {
                                                                  subject_id = c.subject_id,
                                                                  suggestion_order = c.suggestion_order,
                                                                  suggested_subject_id = c.suggested_subject_id,
                                                                  //sugestedSubject = getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions()

                                                              }).ToList();
                foreach (var i in list2)
                {
                    i.sugestedSubject = getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions();
                }
                //list.suggest = list2;
                return list2;
            }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions()
            {
                IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = from c in db.subjects_tbl
                                                         select new SelectListItem
                                                         {
                                                             Text = c.subject_title,
                                                             Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.subject_id).Trim()
                                                         };
                return selectList;
            }

 public class SubjectSuggestionModel
    {
        public int? subject_suggestion_id { get; set; }
        public int? subject_id { get; set; }
        public int? suggested_subject_id { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> sugestedSubject { get; set; }
        public string suggestedSubjectText { get; set; }
        public int? suggestion_order { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your Model? Have you verified that the model contains the expected items... especially `Model.sugestedSubject`?

Comment: Controller action code, too, while you're at it.

Comment: I have updted the code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that you're not setting one of the options in `Model[i].sugestedSubject` to selected in your controller.

I'm guessing that `Model[i].sugestedSubject` is a `SelectList` so when you add the values, make sure you use the `suggested_subject_id` as the `object selectedValue` parameter in your `SelectList` constructor

in your `getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions` function you should add a `subject_id` parameter

`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions(double subject_id)`

then pass it in when you get the list

```
foreach (var i in list2)
{
   i.sugestedSubject = getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions(i.subject_id);
}
```

in your function, use this id to set the selected item.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getsubjectIEnumLsistSuggestions(double subject_id)
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = 
        from c in db.subjects_tbl
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.subject_title,
            Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.subject_id).Trim(),
            Selected = c.subject_id = subject_id
        };
    return selectList;
}
```

Comment: I have added the updated code and in the select list i can see all of the vlaues yet the ifnomration can be selected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

sugestedSubject should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. One of the ID in this should match suggested_subject_id.

Comment: they do, but this is still not mtach